# Setting a domainusers P.O. Box via Powershell set-ADUser doesn't work?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I'm just wondering if anyone of you is using powershell to set a users P.O. Box via
`Set-ADUser`

Im comparing domainaccounts between two different domains and let my script write the differences back to one of the DCs. At the first run, the script detects that there's a different POBox on DC1 than on DC2 and writes the one from DC1 back to DC2.

This works perfectly well with all of the atributes except the postOfficeBox.
As stated above, on the first run, the script detects the changes and writes the changes back. That does not apply to the postOfficeBox however. If I open the userobject on DC2, it remains blank! What is even more strange is, that the script doesn't detect that the POBox is blank if I run it again! I have to modify the postOfficeBox manually in order for the script to see any changes again. (and with blank I mean not even spaces)

All other attributes are working fine. Is this a possible bug on Win Server 2012 and WPS?

Here's the code:

```
$attributes = "c","co","company","countryCode","department","displayName","postOfficeBox","sAMAccountName" 
$user1 = Try{Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Properties $attributes}
catch{}
$user2 = try{Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Properties $attributes -Credential $AdminCredentials -Server $dc2}
catch{}

if ($user1.SamAccountName -eq $user2.SamAccountName) {
    $chk_modified = @{}
    $attributes | ? { $user1.$_ -ne $user2.$_ } | % {
        $chk_modified[$_] = $user2.$_
        }
if ($chk_modified.Count -ge 1) {
Set-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Replace $chk_modified
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a field in Active Directory called 'POBox' is this the field you mean?

Here is how I would update it
    `Get-ADUser $userName | Set-ADUser -POBox $pobox -Credential $cred`

or this:

```
'Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName | Set-ADUser -postOfficeBox "the new box 42" -credential $cred'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes. It's the field P.O. Box under address tab. it is adresses via postOfficeBox.

Comment: so in my case it would look like 'Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName | Set-ADUser -Replace @{postOfficeBox="the new box 42"}'
other than that, my script does the same as yours. But the field for P.O. Box is always empty. (however: it works by writing the set-aduser manually in an empty powershell)